# Can ViewModel return other ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I was playing with MVVM in swift and encountered this situation: 
I created model for tableView which contains list of the objects and count for the objects. Something like

```
class TableViewViewModel {
    var count : Int = 0
    var objects = [MyObjects]()
    //...
    func configure(objs: [MyObjects]){
        self.objects = objs
        self.count = objs.count
    }
}
```

So I added something like

```
func getObjectAtIndex(index: Int) -> CellViewModel {
    let cellObject = CellViewModel(objects[row])
    return cellObject
}
```

Does this breaks whole MVVM philosophy? Is this some kind of antipattern?

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'm using MVVM design too, and on IOS since Apple pushes on the MVC design pattern, a lot of times I find my self doing stuff that is not 100% MVVM oriented, but suits the best for IOS programming.

Second, you call "cellObject" an object that is actually as CellViewModel, this naming convention is very confusing.

Third and last, YES, MVVM design pattern by concept,  ViewModels can know about ether ViewModels, and Views can know about ether  Views. I'ts totally Ok.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It's just example that I wrote while writing the question, I will change that to cellVM. Regarding third part, that was my concern since it seems impossible to see vertical part of the MVVM - horizontal is straight forward. And for first, rules are to be guidelines, not to follow blindly :)  but it shouldn't lead to antipattern, hence the question. Thanks again